# Windows Detect Android Phone as Keyboard Input Device

Tags: android, keyboard, driver

I recently switched to using a password management system for a few things, and I created (potentially stupidly) long passwords for some of the accounts.  I have the system set up on my phone, and I would like to share/transmit the password as text from my phone to a computer (via usb).  The trouble is, I can't install anything on the computer, so I really need to be able to have the phone be detected as a keyboard input device (much like a yubikey).

I notice that when I connect my phone I can choose to charge or use it as a removable storage, but it would be nice to have an option for detecting as a keyboard here.

Ideas?

*I can't connect my phone as removable storage on this computer either which is why I think if I can detect as keyboard then I can just transmit the data via text input.